# Elastic search query returning unexpected results on large datasets

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic search database with 3.3 million records in it.  When I run a search like this

```
elasticClient.Search<ElasticIndex>(s => s.Size(100).From(0).Query(q =>
            q.MatchPhrasePrefix(f => f.OnField(i => i.Search).Query("a.b.c.d.e.f")))).Total
```

I get 27 results which is what I expect.  When I run a query like this

```
elasticClient.Search<ElasticIndex>(s => s.Size(100).From(0).Query(q =>
            q.MatchPhrasePrefix(f => f.OnField(i => i.Search).Query("a.b.c")))).Total
```

I get 2,133 results witch is what I expect. But when I run a query like this

```
elasticClient.Search<ElasticIndex>(s => s.Size(100).From(0).Query(q =>
            q.MatchPhrasePrefix(f => f.OnField(i => i.Search).Query("a.b.c")) &&
            q.MatchPhrasePrefix(f => f.OnField(i => i.Search).Query("a.b.c.d.e.f")))).Total
```

I get 0 results.  I would expect to get the 27 that a.b.c.d.e.f got as a.b.c is just a substring of a.b.c.d.e.f.

What is even stranger to me is if I take the 27 documents and copy then to an index all of there own then run the query, it returns then expected 27 results.  If I start moving documents from the large index to the new index somewhere around 50,000 to 80,000 documents the query start returning less results.  If I continue to copy over documents the query continues to return less until it returns 0 but querying for either MatchPrasePrefix (a.b.c or a.b.c.d.e.f) still returns the correct results only the && of the 2 is returning the wrong results.

I understand the querying for a.b.c and a.b.c.d.e.f is not useful and I could just do the a.b.c.d.e.f but my end users are doing searches like this and would like for it to work without having to parse the incoming search and try to find redundant terms and remove then prior to sending to the database.  I feel like there must be a timeout option I am missing or something.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is the elastic search json query.  Just a.b.c.d.e.f

```
    {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "search": {
        "type": "phrase_prefix",
        "query": "a.b.c.d.e.f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With both

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "search": {
              "type": "phrase_prefix",
              "query": "a.b.c.d.e.f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "search": {
              "type": "phrase_prefix",
              "query": "a.b.c"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you swap the two queries in the last bit of code, i.e. you first filter for a.b.c.d.e.f and then a.b.c.?

Comment: @FrancescoB. same thing still returns 0 results.

Comment: Take a look at a document that you expect to match with the Explain API and the given query (looks like you're using Elasticsearch 1.x): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-explain.html.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion.  It ends up that is is the search for a.b.c that is failing.  phrase_prefix finds 50 terms that start with a.b.c then finds documents that have one of thous 50 terms.  On the large dataset a.b.c.d.e.f was not one of the 50 terms so it failed to find the document.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html  Does anyone know of an alternative to phrase_prefix that would work for large datasets?

Comment: @Cedar Would you be able to explain a bit more about what the query is trying to achieve? At the moment, `must` clause phrase prefix on `a.b.c` is superfluous because it is covered by `must` clause phrase prefix on `a.b.c.d.e.f`. If you're able to add some details about what you're trying to achieve to the question, may be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: @RussCam I found a solution.  I wanted to be able to find everything that started with a.b.c and thought it was working but really it was just finding documents that had a match of 50 phrase that matched that string.  Researching more it looks like the default analyzer does not strip out dots if there is no space after so using that analyzer I am able to just do a wild card search instead of a phrase_prefix.  Thanks for your help the explain query was key to understanding what was happening.